If $x \ne 0$ then $1/(1/x) = x$
I am reading Rudin's Analysis (baby rudin). This is part of proposition 1.15 (d) and Rudin omits the proof. So, I wanted to prove it myself. Actually, this will follow from earlier  proposition (1.15 c), which states that if $x \ne 0 $ and $xy = 1$ then $y = 1/x$. If we replace $x$ by $1/x$ (and since $x \cdot (1/x) = 1$), and letting $y = x$, it will follow the result. But the problem is that, I need to first prove that if $x \ne 0$ then $(1/x) \ne 0$. This can be proven assuming that $x \cdot 0 = 0$. But, this result is proven by Rudin in later proposition (1.16 a). So, I am assuming that we are expected to prove proposition 1.15 (d) without assuming that $x \cdot 0 = 0$. I need some guidance here.

How are you defining $\frac 1x$?  I'd have thought that, $x\neq 0$, $x\times \frac 1x=1$ was the definition.

lulu, if $x \ne 0 $, then existence of $(1/x)$ is assured by the axiom $M5$.

I asked for your definition of the expression.  As I say, I'd have thought that what you were after was essentially a tautology.  I guess you do need to remark that, if $x\neq 0$ then $\frac 1x\neq 0$, but that follows at once from $x\times \frac 1x=1$.

I don't know how Rudin states it, but he shouldn't entangle the existence axiom with the definition.  If he does, then yes, you might need to prove something more.

Brian, I think Rudin should have included proposition 1.16 before proposition 1.15, so that result $0x = 0$ can be used to prove what I stated. That is only logical answer I can think of. Most of other analysis books prove the result $0x = 0$, but they do not necessarily include the result I wanted to prove. Which means that this result is pushed into the exercises section where we can assume that $0x = 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and my result follows easily.

We have that $x \times \frac 1 x = 1$, and we have that $\frac 1 x \times \frac {1}{\frac 1 x} =1$.
Thus, applying 1.15 (a): $x = \frac {1}{\frac 1 x}$.
As you can see in the text, the proof of 1.16 (a): $0 \times x =0$ does not need the results of 1.15. This means that we can apply it directly to Axiom M5: $x \times \frac 1 x =1$.
Assume $x \ne 0$ and suppose that $\frac 1 x =0$; then, using 1.16 (a), we have $x \times \frac 1 x =0$, and thus $1=0$, contradicting non-triviality (somewhere we must have it; see E.Bloch, page 63).

How does this deal with the question about needing to show $\frac1x \not = 0$  in order to have $\frac {1}{\frac 1 x}$ at all?

Mauro, but you are using result of proposition 1.16 (a) in the proof of proposition 1.15 (d). So, is it ok to use later results in the book to prove earlier results ? That was my whole point.

@user9026 - which result of 1.16 (a) I've used in the first two lines poof?

you say "using 1.16 (a), we have $x \times \frac{1}{x}  = 0$ " in second last line and then come to the contradiction that $1 = 0$

@user9026 two parts: 1) first lines: the proof of 1.15d using 1.15a. 2) the second part is the proof of if $x \ne 0$ then... using 1.16a that can be proved independently form the 1.15's

@Mauro,  ok I think I got it. So, we can use 1.16(a) to prove the proposition 1.15 (d).  I think Rudin should have inclueded1.16 before 1.15, so that result of 1.16 can be used to prove 1.15 (d). Usually we don't use later results to prove earlier theorems.
